# Finding a non-negative similar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be some matrix. Is there a way to decide whether there exists an invertible matrix $P$, such that the matrix:

$$
A = P^{-1}BP
$$

Is non-negative?  (That is - all the entries in the matrix are non-negative)

Basically - given a linear transformation, I want to find a different base, in which the transformation matrix of this linear transformation is non-negative.
For example, for the matrix:

$$
B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I have the matrix:

$$
P=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\ 1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And
$$
P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ -1&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And:

$$
A=P^{-1}BP=
\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\ 1 &1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is there a way to efficiently decide if such matrix $P$ exists, and to find it?

Comment: I assume that you are talking about real matrices. Well, notice that, if such an $A$ exists, then trace($B^{m}$) is non-negative for all non-negative integers $m$.

Comment: a necessary condition is that $B$ has a real nonnegative eigenvalue $\lambda$, and any other eigenvalue $\lambda'$ satisfies $|\lambda'|\leq\lambda$ (Perron-Frobenius theorem)

Comment: In the 2 by 2 case, if $tr(B) \geq 0$ and $B$ has real eigenvalues, then it is similar to a nonnegative matrix (symmetric, even).

Comment: There are necessary and sufficient conditions so that *some power* of $B$ is conjugate to a matrix with strictly positive entries, but this is not what you are are looking for. In general, conjugacy to a primitive matrix (a matrix with all entries nonnegative, and some power of the matrix is strictly positive) is a very difficult prolem.